# Wordpress with Xampp local server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, xampp

Until now when I've created a new site it was always on a preconfigured hosting service. Currently, I'm working on a website for a friend of mine. Since he has not yet bought the domain and a hosting service I'm trying to set up XAMPP and Wordpress on my local computer. 
I've found a detailed guide [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdvVKywGlc0&ab_channel=DerekBanas). I've installed the XAMPP then the Apache and MySQL. When I get to the part where I'm adding a password to SQL(timeframe on the youtube clip - 9:11) :

[image: SQL]
[image: phpmyadmin config.inc editing]

and I get the password prompt on my phpMyAdmin in the localhost. There whatever password and username I try it does not work.

[image: phpMyAdmin login prompt]

However, I've tried to skip this step and do not add any password. I've gone directly to try and make a database for WordPress. Then I get the loading screen infinitely and it does not create or saves the changes I made in phpMyAdmin.

So my question is does anybody have an Idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

change the password in config.inc file. By default there is no password for the user 'root' in xampp

Comment: If you check the pictures you can clearly see that I've changed the password

Comment: it's blank in the picture so i thought you didn't change it in config.inc file

Comment: I guess you have the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811804/phpmyadmin-failed-to-set-session-cookie-maybe-you-are-using-http-instead-of-htt

Comment: So the solution is to clear the browser cache... I've wasted half a day on this stupid error