# Logging in to myPhpAdmin

Tags: php

I try to login in to myPhpAdmin through wamp but after opening the browser local host using root as my username and my password ,then it doesn't log in and it says maybe you are using http not https

Comment: Maybe you are using http instead of https

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811804/phpmyadmin-failed-to-set-session-cookie-maybe-you-are-using-http-instead-of-htt

Answer (score -3):

I found a solution to my problem,,wamp was not good at it So when I did away with it camp let me in into phpMyAdmin very well and easy

Comment: this really doesn't provide much in the way of useful information. If you removed WAMP It implies you already had an instance of phpMyAdmin and mysql running before you installed WAMP. Yet WAMP also installs both of these products as part of it (WAMP is not a single product, just an installer for several others). So maybe you were actually just trying to log into a different instance of MySQL.

Comment: Or maybe some previous webserver was being used before, pointing at a different instance of phpMyAdmin. None of this is clear. To most readers "delete wamp" will not be the solution to being unable to log in to phpMyAdmin. More context is needed for this to make any sense or be useful.